# JSON_EXTRACT MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have problem when i need to make query from json data.

my json data looks like this:

```
{"groups":[{"groupid":"3","group_name":"test group","group_type":"user","office":"1"},{"groupid":"4","group_name":"test group 1","group_type":"user","office":"1"},{"groupid":"21","group_name":"test group 2","group_type":"directory","office":"0"}]}
```

Is it possible to make query that returns only groupids where office=1

Currently i have done this but don't know how to make query for office.

```
select json_extract(test,'$.groups[*].groupid') as groupid from test;
```

Comment: Sounds like you are using Json when you should be using columns for `groupid` and `office`.  _Json functions are a poor substitute for cases when RDBMS works well._

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT('
  SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(`doc_text`, ',
    REPLACE(TRIM('[' FROM TRIM(']' FROM
        JSON_SEARCH(doc_text, 'all', '1', NULL, '$.groups[*].office')
        )
      ),
      'office',
      'groupid'
    ), ') `groupid` FROM `docs`'
) INTO @`sql`
FROM `docs`;
```

See [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=145e13942bf150cbe2cd037e027a7215).